# Send an image from react to flask and return the ocr value back to react

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, ocr

i'm new with react .. i'm trying here to send an image from react to flask, the flask does the ocr processing and send the result back to the react .. i did the part related to send the image from react to flask but i'm stuck now at the part of sending the return from flask to react ..any help ? and thanks in advance

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**app.js**

```
import React  from 'react';

class Main extends React.Component {
      
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageURL: '',
    
    };

    this.handleUploadImage = this.handleUploadImage.bind(this);
    
  }
  
  
  handleUploadImage(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
    data.append('filename', this.fileName.value);
    
    fetch(' http://localhost:5001/ocr ', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
  }
    

  render() {
   

      
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleUploadImage}>
        
        <div>
          <input ref={(ref) => { this.uploadInput = ref; }} type="file" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input ref={(ref) => { this.fileName = ref; }} type="text" placeholder="Enter the desired name of file" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <button>Upload</button>
        </div>
        <ul>
        {}
        </ul>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

**app.py**

```
import os
import io
import requests
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import tempfile
import urllib.request
import easyocr
from flask import Flask, render_template, request , jsonify, make_response
import shutil
import logging
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import numpy as np
import ssl
from flask_cors import CORS , cross_origin


ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """ Special json encoder for numpy types """
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.route('/ocr',methods=['POST','GET'])
@cross_origin(origin='*',headers=['Content-Type'])
def ocr():

    print("Recieved Image File")
    file = request.files['file']
    print('File from the POST request is: {}'.format(file))
    img = Image.open(file.stream)
      # img.show()
    img = img.convert("RGB")
    img.save("recogImage.jpg")
    
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en' , 'ar'])
    bounds = reader.readtext("recogImage.jpg")
    #bounds = reader.readtext(filename)
    
    print('bounds: ',np.array(bounds).tolist())

    response = json.dumps({"bounds": np.array(bounds , dtype=object)}, cls=NumpyEncoder)


    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5001)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your POST request is already returning the response, you just have to handle it in fetch like this:

```
import React  from 'react';

class Main extends React.Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          imageURL: '',
          ocrData: ''
        };

        this.handleUploadImage = this.handleUploadImage.bind(this);

    }


  handleUploadImage(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();

      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
      data.append('filename', this.fileName.value);

      fetch(' http://localhost:5001/ocr ', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
          this.setState({
              ocrData: res.bounds
          }));
  }


  render() {
      const {ocrData} = this.state;

  
      return (
         <form onSubmit={this.handleUploadImage}>
    
         <div>
           <input ref={(ref) => { this.uploadInput = ref; }} type="file" />
         </div>
         <div>
           <input ref={(ref) => { this.fileName = ref; }} type="text" placeholder="Enter the desired name of file" />
         </div>
         <br />
         <div>
           <button>Upload</button>
         </div>
         <ul>
           {}
         </ul>
         <div>{ocrData}</div>
       </form>
);
}
  }

export default Main;
```

Comment: Can yu show me how to print the return in the webpage?.. Show me how to edit my file to print that return

Comment: I have edited the answer. This should work.

Comment: it shows me this error now :
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
  Line 37:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  35 |           this.setState({
  36 |               ocrData: res.bounds
> 37 |           }));
     |             ^
  38 |   }
  39 |
  40 |   render() {
should i remove the ";" or what ?

Comment: My bad, there's an extra parenthesis after setState function, please remove that

Comment: i removed it but still have this error   Line 40:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  38 |   }
  39 | 
> 40 |   render() {
     |   ^
  41 |     const {ocrData} = this.state;
  42 |       
  43 |     return (

Comment: Hi.. Sorry but i still cant find the solution